# How to structure a data content in OPC UA and what exactly means delivering a OPC Specification for a application

Tags: specifications, opc, opc-ua

This question is regarding OPC UA specification design for a industrial application. I am a beginner to OPC UA terminology and wondering what is the process of designing a OPC UA specification. I searched online for tutorials, tools and went through the standard textbook of OPC UA. I have got information in bits and parts but never a structured approach.

Questions

1. Do we have any open source tools that can used to design a OPC UA specification?
2. Do we have any standard document describing the process of designing a OPC UA specification

Any Small clue reasoning to a approach is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused. You don't want to design an "OPC-UA specification"; these specifications already exist, are maintained by the OPC Foundation, and define what OPC-UA actually is.

More likely, you need to develop an application that conforms to or is compatible with OPC-UA in some way. In that case, we'll need to know what it is your application is doing (is it a client or server?) and what language you're planning to develop it in. From there you can determine whether or not you need open source or commercial tools to move forward.

Comment: yea, I was cofused. Thank you for your response.yea, In general do we have some documentation where there is any structured approach in designing the data model for the applications in OPC UA. I might be using both client and server across different interfaces.

Comment: According to my understanding

1. Know what systems that interacts with OPC UA server or client
2. Know what data has to be communicated
3. using the existing interfaces and components, if required of opc ua stack and design the data model
4. choose the respective stack(on programming language) and use the api to develop those operations 

Is my approach right?

do we have any standard templates such as SOA reference templates for OPC UA, which we can take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

Basic bulding blocks for information models are found within the UA companion specifications. A range of working groups develop these for various domains of interest. Standard semantic models are defined to provide interoperability.Look to OPC Foundation site. Provided a companion spec, you might as UA client imediately recognize the adresspace content of a servér you have never seen before. As UA you may provide data to some client you currently not know, but it might recognize the content anyway. And when you connect to another UA that complies with the same companion spec, you might recognize that content to with very little extra effort.